# MySQLi creating menus by insertion with php

Tags: php, mysqli, menu, insert

I'm trying to create a table (done), and add some menus inside. What I mean is, on the website I want to be capable of inserting my menu into my table. I have code here, but I don't know what's wrong with it. I know I need MySQLi compatibility. But, this is beyond me (I already converted a lot of my code so it would be compatible with it, but this code here... I don't know how I could change it.

```
$sql = "insert into pages set VALUES
(
    (1, 'Home', 0, '<p>Home</p>'),
    (2, 'About', 1, '<p>About</p>'),
    (3, 'Services', 1, '<p>Services</p>'),
    (4, 'News', 1, '<p>News</p>'),
    (5, 'Contact', 1, '<p>Contact</p>') 
) ";
```

Comment: specify your database  structure. Also, please think about switching to PDO.

Comment: Oh man, why tags in DB? :~~

Comment: Is this what you mean? "You need to specify your database structure once in the beginning (this is how many columns in your table(s) and what type these columns have)."

If so, 5 columns and the types are varchar, text and int (plus primary).

What does PDO stand for? I am not familiar with it or what it does. I'm not very proficient with PHP just yet.

Comment: @PiLHA what is your concern about?

Comment: @MidevilChaos I think they should stay in the html where is their place.

Comment: @PiLHA How would you make your setup? I learnt how to upload tables and inserting data this way.

Comment: @MidevilChaos I need to see your PHP code to suggest a solution.

Comment: @PiLHA You can get it here:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g8u-n2f

Answer (score 1):

`ENGINE = INNODB CHARSET = UTF8` should be removed from your SQL there. The database engine and charset is used when creating tables, not inserting values.

Also you can not mix `SET` and `VALUES` in your statement. These two SQL statements will perform exactly the same action:

```
INSERT INTO foo SET bar = 1;
INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES(1);
```

You can take a look at [MySQL's documentation on INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to see what parameters are permitted in an INSERT statement.

Comment: Ok, for now, I edited the statement about the engine. I will take a look at the rest and study it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, with ID 1 and 2 already taken, I have to go with ID's 3-6. I had accidentally looked at my problem from a "create table" perspective, as opposed to the "insert into" perspective. @Niklas Modess you made me realize my dumb error! Thank you my Swedish friend!

```
mysqli_query ($conn, "INSERT INTO pages (pageID, pageTitle, isRoot, pageCont) 
VALUES
(3, 'About', 1, '<p>Sample Sample content</p>'),
(4, 'Services', 1, '<p>Sample Sample content</p>'),
(5, 'News', 1, '<p>Sample Sample content</p>'),
(6, 'Contact', 1, '<p>Sample Sample content</p>')");
```